# best way to split curly-brace-enclosed messages into multiple lines?

Tags: python, json, regex, unix

I have the following file, which supposed to be multi-line json file, but everything is in oneline:

```
{"id":0, "val":123}{"id":1,"val":345}{"id":2, "val":3434}....
```

In order to load it into python to do analysis, i need to break it into multiple lines first, like this:

```
{"id":0, "val":123}
{"id":1,"val":345}
{"id":2, "val":3434}
...
```

what is the best tool to do so? awk? sed? python?

Answer (score 2):

Just use python and `.replace` function like this

```
with open('filename') as f:
    text = f.read().replace('}', '}\n')

with open('filename.edit', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

This will add `\n` after `}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string using regex lookarounds, for instance:

```
(?<=})(?={)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/eS3nS9/1)**

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?<=})(?={)')
test_str = u"{\"id\":0, \"val\":123}{\"id\":1,\"val\":345}{\"id\":2, \"val\":3434}"
subst = u"\n"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

**[IdeOne demo](http://ideone.com/zrdVId)**

[image]

Comment: I believe a `regex` module is necessary for this approach to work. `re` can't split with empty string. Did you try that in code?

Comment: Hi @stribizhev, I just wrote the idea not a fully working example. Updated now, thanks for the comment

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood me, have a [look at the Python code](http://ideone.com/fDc8rO). The string is not split: `[u'{"id":0, "val":123}{"id":1,"val":345}{"id":2, "val":3434}']`

Comment: @stribizhev oh, thank you very much for the code. I had no idea about it... I'm a java person lol. Have just updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

For unix tools use awk:

```
awk -v RS='}' 'NF{print $0 "}"}' file
{"id":0, "val":123}
{"id":1,"val":345}
{"id":2, "val":3434}
```

Or gnu-sed:

```
sed 's/}/&\n/g' file
{"id":0, "val":123}
{"id":1,"val":345}
{"id":2, "val":3434}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way here it seems to be using regular expressions - it saves you necessity of writing any code.

for instance in Vim you could use something like this: `%s/}/}\r/g`

In any other editor there should be `\n` instead of `\r` i guess

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your input is sufficiently uncomplicated that regex-based approaches will suffice, but the best way to accomplish the general task you describe (i.e., producing jsonlines from a JSON stream) is to use a JSON-aware tool. One such is jq.  At any rate, the following is simple, fast, and effective:

```
$ jq -c . input.json
```

The output can of course be redirected to a file.

(There is one caveat: jq converts input numbers to IEEE 754 64-bit numbers, so 1e1000 on input becomes its IEEE 754 64-bit approximation on output.)

For details about jq, see https://stedolan.github.io/jq